# WebDriver drag and drop an element to a specific target area

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver

Using WebDriver and Junit 4.11, I have a slider element (changes the opacity of a component from 0-100%) that I want to clickAndHold, then release at a certain point.

I'm able to drag and drop components onto a target area, then change the value by finding the text box elements for the x and y axis. But in this instance I need to automate a slider. Is this even possible?

HTML code below for the slider:

```
<div class="inputWrapper"> <input type="range" value="1" name="opacity" id="c409" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" class="t-textInput-A"><span class="units">%</span><div class="sliderTooltip" style="display: none; margin-left: 97px;">100%</div> </div>
```

The slider is currently set to 100%, but how can I grab the element and drag and drop it to say, for example, 10%?

I have taken a screenshot to illustrate what it is I am attempting to grab: http://screencast.com/t/YjdoFtSG

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It`s simply. Send value to field and trigger 'change' event at this field.
As example execute this script in browser:

```
    arguments[0].valueAsNumber = arguments[1];
    var mEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
    mEvent.initEvent('change', true, true);
    arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mEvent);
```

- `argument[0]` - input type=range web element
- `argument[1]` - needed size

Attention, this example work at Firefox and Chrome, but not working at Internet Explorer. Read docs about "fireEvent" in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and experiment with these functions (I'm using phpwebdriver)

```
/**
     * Move the mouse by an offset of the specificed element.
     * If no element is specified, the move is relative to the current mouse cursor.
     * If an element is provided but no offset, the mouse will be moved to the center of the element.
     * If the element is not visible, it will be scrolled into view.
     *
     * @param WebElement $element
     * ID of the element to move to. If not specified or is null,
     * the offset is relative to current position of the mouse.
     * @param integer $xoffset
     * X offset to move to, relative to the top-left corner of the element.
     * If not specified, the mouse will move to the middle of the element.
     * @param integer $yoffset
     * Y offset to move to, relative to the top-left corner of the element.
     * If not specified, the mouse will move to the middle of the element.
     */
    public function moveTo($element = null, $xoffset = null, $yoffset = null)
    {
        $request = $this->requestURL . "/moveto";
        $session = $this->curlInit($request);

        $array = explode('/', $element->requestURL);        
        $id = $array[count($array) - 1];        
        $args = array();
        if($element) $args['element'] = $id;
        if($xoffset) $args['xoffset'] = intval($xoffset);
        if($yoffset) $args['yoffset'] = intval($yoffset);
        if(empty($args))
            $this->preparePOST($session, null);
        else{
            $postargs = json_encode($args);
            $this->preparePOST($session, $postargs);
        }
        curl_exec($session);
    }

    /**
     * Click and hold the left mouse button (at the coordinates set by the last moveto command). 
     * Note that the next mouse-related command that should follow is buttonUp() . 
     * Any other mouse command (such as click() or another call to buttonDown()) will yield undefined behaviour.
     * 
     * @param integer $button
     * Which button, enum: {LEFT = 0, MIDDLE = 1 , RIGHT = 2}. 
     * Defaults to the left mouse button if not specified.
     */
    public function buttonDown()
    {
        $request = $this->requestURL . "/buttondown";
        $session = $this->curlInit($request);
        $this->preparePOST($session, null);
        curl_exec($session);
    }
    /**
     * Releases the mouse button previously held (where the mouse is currently at). 
     * Must be called once for every buttonDown() command issued. 
     * See the note in click and buttonDown() about implications of out-of-order commands.
     * 
     * @param integer $button
     * Which button, enum: {LEFT = 0, MIDDLE = 1 , RIGHT = 2}. 
     * Defaults to the left mouse button if not specified.
     */
    public function buttonUp()
    {
        $request = $this->requestURL . "/buttonup";
        $session = $this->curlInit($request);
        $this->preparePOST($session, null);
        curl_exec($session);
    }

    /**
     * Maximize the specified window if not already maximized. 
     * If the :windowHandle URL parameter is "current", the currently active window will be maximized.
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I've generally had to drop via coordinates. If you're using clickAndHold I assume you are stringing together actions so for the second action, do:

moveByOffset(-100, 0)

or whatever the correct move size is. That will move the mouse from the position its presently in (after clickAndHold) left by 100px which should drag the slider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @stirno. I was aware of this command although I haven't been successful in implementing it into my test. It seems as though the code in my question appears greyed out, with #document-fragment before the div. So I'm wondering is this locked out therefore not allowing me to be able to automate the slider at all? I've included a screenshot which illustrates the greyed out code. http://screencast.com/t/zGUj64ZRS